# Битрикс: автоматическое создание карты сайта (агент)

Tags: битрикс, cron, sitemap

Одна из опций в Битрикс-1C - Google Sitemap.

Как создать агента, который будет создавать эту карту сайта автоматически? Имеется, ввиду, что там прописать, там нужно прописывать код какой-то функции...

Answer (score 2):

Код функции прописать не получится за ее отсутствием.
Вам надо зайти в `/bitrix/modules/search/admin/search_sitemap.php` и преобразовать тот код, который выполняется по `$_REQUEST["Generate"]=="Y"` в функцию.

Достаточно простая реализация описана тут: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/oracle/254.php?commentId=19459#19459